# Forward rolling window in dataframe in r calling previous observation

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to create a function to apply to a variable in a dataframe that, for a windows of 2 days forward from the current observation, calculate the number of days that takes a variable to change in a positive number.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
VarA     VarB     Date         Diff
 1         1      2007-04-09    NA 
 1         1      2007-04-10    0  
 1         1      2007-04-11   -2  
 1         1      2007-04-12    0  
 1         1      2007-04-13    2  
 1         1      2007-04-14    0  
 1         1      2007-04-15   -2  
 1         1      2007-04-16    1  
 1         1      2007-04-17   -4  
 1         1      2007-04-18    0  
 1         1      2007-04-17    0  
 1         1      2007-04-18    0
```

I want to create a new variable in the following cases:

1. For each VarA, each VarB, and each Date, if Diff is not negative (could be NA), assign the new variable a value of 0
2. If Diff has a negative number, assign 1 to that date observation, and the next ones until: a) a maximum of two days after the negative Diff is reached; or b) if Diff is different from zero in the days after and before the two days limit. In both cases, VarC should a value of 0 again.

It should look like the following:

```
     VarA     VarB     Date         Diff   VarC
      1         1      2007-04-09    NA     0
      1         1      2007-04-10    0      0
      1         1      2007-04-11   -2      1
      1         1      2007-04-12    0      1
      1         1      2007-04-13    2      0
      1         1      2007-04-14    0      0
      1         1      2007-04-15   -2      1
      1         1      2007-04-16    1      0
      1         1      2007-04-17   -4      0
      1         1      2007-04-18    0      0
      1         1      2007-04-17    0      0
      1         1      2007-04-18    0      0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
db$VarC <- 0

for (i in unique(db$VarA)) {
 for (j in unique(db$VarB)) {
  subset.data.frame(db, VarA == i & VarB == j)
   for (n in 1 : lenght(db$Date)) db$VarC[n] <- 
     ifelse(db$Diff[n] < 0, 1,                                                         
     ifelse (db$VarC[n-1] ==1 && db$Diff[n] <0, 1, 0))
}
}
```

But the problem is that the script is too much time consuming. I have to run it for 100 million observations, and it could run for days. I tried using dplyr and calling the .Last.value function as in:

```
db <- db %>% group_by(VarA, VarB) %>% rowwise() %>% 
 mutate( VarC = ifelse(Diff <0, 1 , ifelse(.Last.value == 1 & Diff < 
   0, 1, 0))) )
```

But the problem is that `dplyr` (and as far as I know, `data.table`) cannot handle the "check the previous row" implicit in the algorithm. Using `lag` does not help either. I wonder if there is any faster way to do the trick.

Comment: `for (n in db$Date)` change to `for (n in 1 : length(db$Date))` will clear the error

Comment: Thanks @Wen for the answer. Nevertheless, I am trying the code with a large database, and the loop seems to be not ending. I have the results in VarC, but the loop is too time consuming. Even it seems to continue after the code seems to continue. Is there any way to made the code more quick? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need `group_by`

Comment: @Wen, I try using dplyr, but the problem is I do not how to call a previous value inside dplyr. 'db <-
  db %>% group_by(VarA, VarB) %>%
  mutate(VarC = ifelse (db$Diff < 0 | (VarC[i-1] == 1 &&
                                                    db$Diff == 0), 1, 0)

Comment: something like `dat%>%group_by(VarA,VarB)%>%dplyr::mutate(VarC=ifelse(Diff<0,1,ifelse(lag(VarC)==1&Diff<0,1,0)))`

Comment: @Wen, thanks for the code. Nevertheless, as far as I understand `lag` it is not apply row wise. I change the code a little bit (and use .Last.value) but the problem is that the second `ifelse` does not seems to work. db <- 
db %>% group_by(VarA, VarB) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    VarC = ifelse(Diff <0, 1 , ifelse(.Last.value == 1 & Diff < 0, 1, 0)))
)